# discriminant of $ a|z_{1}|^2+b |z_{2}|^2+c|z_{3}|^2 +2d Re(z_{1} \bar{z_{2}}) +2e Re(z_{2} \bar{z_{3}}) +2f Re(z_{3} \bar{z_{1}}) \geq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, quadratic-forms

I want to know about discriminant of $ a |z_{1}|^2+b |z_{2}|^2+c|z_{3}|^2 +2d Re(z_{1} \bar{z_{2}}) +2e Re(z_{2} \bar{z_{3}}) +2f Re(z_{3} \bar{z_{1}}) \geq 0 $ where $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbf{C}$.
I tried searching for it, in wikiepedia, I came to know this,
ax² + 2bxy + cy² + 2dxz + 2eyz + fz² = 0  ----(1)

The discriminant of this quadratic form is determined by evaluating the following determinant:
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & d \\
b & c & e \\
d & e & f \\
\end{vmatrix}
Is it right to say that discriminant is negative if (1) takes only positive values like we do for quadratic in real coefficients.
Please help me in this regard.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you really want to have $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb R$    because you put $\geq 0$ at the end.        write it over with $z_1 = x_1 + i y_1,$  same for $z_2, z_3,$  the outcome is that you  have a quadratic form in six real variables, there is a six by six matrix that goes with it. .....  Last paragraph, you then say "like...in real coefficients. "  You will need to clarify some issues.